# Genymotion "Unable to load VirtualBox engine" on Fedora 23

Tags: android, linux, virtualbox, fedora, android-virtual-device

After installing `genymotion` it turned out that `genymotion` needed some 64bit libraries which where not present in `fedora 23`.

Installed them, now this error shows up about `VirtualBox` while trying to run `genymotion`:

```
Unable to load VirtualBox engine.Make sure that it is properly installed before starting Genymotion.
```

I am certain that no errors occurred while installing `VirtualBox`. Anyways, here's the log from `genymotion`.

```
Apr 7 18:32:00 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****   
Apr 7 18:32:00 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion 2.6.0   
Apr 7 18:32:04 [Genymotion] [Error] Network error while retrieving JSON content:  0  
Apr 7 18:32:04 [Genymotion] [Error] [getGenymotionLastVersion] Bad request: "/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"   
Apr 7 18:32:04 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to get last Genymotion version number from server:  0   
Apr 7 18:32:05 [Genymotion] [Warning] QIODevice::read: device not open   
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Error] [createHostOnlyInterface] Creating new host-only interface   
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Error] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "create") returns 1   
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Error] Output command: "0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE    
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter   
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory   
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface   
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp"    
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Error] [createHostOnlyInterface] Failed to create interface   
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Error] "Fail to load vboxmanage plugin from /opt/genymobile/genymotion/plugins/"   
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Error] VM Engine failed to load   
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to find VM Engine. Plugin loading aborted.    
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "/opt/genymobile/genymotion/tools/glewinfo" with args ()    
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "lsmod" with args ()    
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "lspci" with args ()   
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "ip" with args ("rule")    
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "ip" with args ("route")   
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "free" with args ()   
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "ps" with args ("afx")   
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "df" with args ("-kh")   
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "dmesg" with args ()   
Apr 7 18:32:06 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "cat" with args ("/proc/cpuinfo")   
Apr 7 18:32:21 [Genymotion] [Error] **** STOPPING GENYMOTION WITH ERROR ****   
Apr 7 18:32:21 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STOPPING GENYMOTION  ****   
Apr 7 18:32:21 [Genymotion] [Error] [Stats] Can't open database:  QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")      
Apr 7 18:32:21 [Genymotion] [Warning] QSqlQuery::exec: database not open     
Apr 7 18:32:21 [Genymotion] [Warning] [Stats] SQLite error: QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
```

I'm new to `Linux` and `VirtualBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! Found out what the problem was. Writing this answer so that it might help someone else with a similar problem.

The problem was with virtualbox, when genymotion would run it, virtualbox needed to point to the kernal. It turns out I had installed the required packages but weren't the same version as my kernel. So, all i had to do was update the packages.

The packges in step 2 are required by virtualbox, better update the system before installing them; ensuring the system automatically downloads the appropriate versions of those packages.

1) Update kernel/system,

```
dnf update
```

2) Install the following packages,

```
dnf install dkms gcc kernel-headers kernel-devel
```

reference: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#install-linux-host